# Test Convergence of the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Is
>   $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}$$
>   Convergent or Divergent? If convergent, find the sum. If Divergent, explain why.

Since it is continuous, positive, and decreasing I used the integral test:

$$\int^\infty_1\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}\Rightarrow \int^\infty_1 \frac25dn +\int^\infty_1ndn+2\int^\infty_12n^2$$

$$\frac25\bigg[n\bigg]^\infty_1+\frac25\bigg[\frac{n^2}{2}\bigg]^\infty_1+2\bigg[\frac{n^3}{3}\bigg]^\infty_1$$

$$\infty+\infty+\infty=\infty; \text{Divergent by the Integral Test}$$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: I'm afraid it seems that you broke up the fraction $\frac{x}{a+b+c} = \frac{x}{a} + \frac{x}{b} + \frac{x}{c}$.  Unfortunately, you cannot break fractions apart this way.  The denominator must remain the same, or you need to use a partial fraction decomposition.  There is an easy test to use for this though, the "basic divergence test".  If a series converges the summand must approach zero.  By contrapositive, if the summand doesn't approach zero, then the series diverges.

Comment: Wow, I did not even realize I did that. It's late haha.

Comment: I think the answer I posted walked through the steps well enough. Tell me if you'd like to see more steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+2n+1}$$

$\text{If}\lim _{n\to \infty }a_n\ne 0 \ \text{then}\sum a_n\mathrm{\:diverges}$

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2}\cdot \frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)\:$$
Then the $n^2$ cancel

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

After taking the limit you get

so $\frac{2}{5+0+0}=\frac{2}{5}$$\ne $ $\:0\:$

So it's divergent!

Comment: yep, was just about to post this! Thanks for confirming though :)

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark to choose an answer!! :D

Comment: You're the best!

Comment: Right back at you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the simplest necessary condition for convergence: the general term must tend to zero as $n\to \infty$.

Your answer is wrong.  It is based on the erroneous computation $$\frac{A}{B+C+D}= \frac{A}{B}+\frac{A}{C}+\frac{A}{D}.$$

Comment: That is not true. We can conclude that the series is divergent if the general term is nonzero as $n\to \infty$, but if the general term is zero, we cannot conclude convergence. In this case, the general term simplifies to $\frac{2}{5}$ as $n\to \infty$, so the series is divergent.

Comment: Edited to clarify my point.